# Auto Scaling: Stop EC2 instances from starting with "scale-in protection"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I recently noticed a strange phenomenon on an AWS auto scaling group. When new instances are launched, they start with "scale-in" protection.

From my understanding, that does not make much sense, as it will soon prevent stopping instances and the whole group will run with the number of instances needed at peek hours.

Is there a setting that allows to control that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Auto Scaling configuration, there is a setting called "Instance Protection".

It was set to "Protected from Scale In". That explains why EC2 instances started from the Auto Scaling Group had "scale-in protection" by default.